# Heartbeat API: How to access data already enqueued?

Tags: jquery, javascript, heartbeat-api

I'm having problems when trying to access data that I've queued using the Heartbeat API.

I'm queuing data using `wp.heartbeat.enqueue()`. For example:

```
var data = { 
    my_key: 'value'
};
wp.heartbeat.enqueue( 'my_handle', data, false );
```

Then later on in my script, I'd like to access the data I've queued. For example:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '#button', function() {
    // Here, I want to access the data I've enqueued.
});
```

I've tried doing the following but that doesn't work:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '#button', function() {
    var my_data = wp.heartbeat.getQueuedItem( 'my_handle' );
    alert( my_data.data.my_key );
});
```

Hoping someone can suggest where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem was to change `my_data.data.my_key` to `my_data.my_key`. For example:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '#button', function() {
    var my_data = wp.heartbeat.getQueuedItem( 'my_handle' );
    alert( my_data.my_key );
});
```

The queued data can be easily accessed now.